# Create a signal with Gtkmm

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am using the gtkmm library with C++, and I am trying to create a signal which allows to change current tab, but it does not work.

Actually I think the problem comes from this line:

```
menuit->signal_activate().connect([&bo]() {bo->next_page();});
```

Where:

```
menuit = Gtk::MenuItem
bo = Gtk::Notebook
```

The code compiles well, but when executing I get this line :

```
Segmentation fault
(program exited with code: 139)
```

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: This is not "creating a signal". This is connecting to a signal, or connecting a signal handler to a signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
menuit->signal_activate().connect([&bo]() {bo->next_page();});
```

You're capturing `bo` by reference, so at the time the signal is executed, I guess the capture became a dangling reference.

Try by copy (after all, `bo` is a pointer):

```
menuit->signal_activate().connect([bo]() {bo->next_page();});
```