# cout overwrites some of my pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, runtime-error, cout

I have a strange problem where a simple cout messes up my previously defined pointers. Here is the code:

```
union Value {
    bool a;
    long long val;
    int next;
};

struct Clos { //not a "closure" in its actual sense.
    vector<Value**> args;
    function<void()> method;
};

Clos* prepare() {
  Clos* closure = new Clos();

  Value* a = nullptr; //these values do not exist yet, but I need these pointers to rename them at RT
  Value* b = nullptr;
  Value* out = new Value; //this exists
  closure->args.push_back(&a); //save adresses to rename them later
  closure->args.push_back(&b);
  closure->method = [&a, &b, &out](){out->val = a->val + b->val;}; //just some operation on arguments
  return closure;
}
```

Here I create an object "closure" with bound function (a "method") that uses  not-yet-defined pointers as arguments, which will be bound later at runtime.

Later:

```
 int main(void) {
  Clos* clos = prepare();
  Value a; //now we get input values at RT
  a.val = 7;
  Value b;
  b.val = 8;
  *clos->args[0] = &a; //we bind them to previously "dangling" pointers
  *clos->args[1] = &b;
  cout << "WOLOLOLOLO"; //<<<<---- COMMENT OUT THIS LINE AND BOOM!
  clos->method(); //this works, as long cout is not called 
}
```

Is there a problem with how I initially define a and b (as nullpointers?) Do they get deallocated or something? I've tried making them "static" but it does not work either. Something is wrong on general level :(

Comment: This looks like undefined behavior to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a signal with Gtkmm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822089/create-a-signal-with-gtkmm)

Comment: You probably need to post a COMPLETE set of code that can be run.

Comment: Seems like you have a misconception of how closures work.  What is the point of your `closure->args`?  Are you trying to make it where you can change what `a` and `b` mean inside of `eval`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful no I couldn't find an answer there.

Comment: Your pointer initially taken are on the stack. I guess you justleft that stackframe and the pointers became stale. Without a suitably complete code it is impossible to tell. Also, I'm pretty sure `{.val = 17}` is not valid C++.

Comment: Hi all, I've added a full code. Yes, I think the declaration of pointers on the stack is wrong, but how I allocate pointers on the heap which are not yet defined?
@DietmarKühl this is a valid assignment.

Comment: @artemonster -- *this is a valid assignment* -- [Doesn't compile with Visual Studio 2015](http://rextester.com/TVNF59274).  This is more than likely an extension,and not standard C++.

Comment: @artemonster: I'm roughly 100% certain that C++ does _not_ have designated initializers! It may compile with the compiler you are using but that doesn't make it valid C++. In Oulu a [paper proposing designated initializer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0329r0.pdf) was discussed. The idea in general was accepted but not for C++17.

Comment: @DietmarKühl oh I see. I suppose gcc will eat everything :D I'll modify the code.

Comment: I think you might be wanting something more like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8eedd6f6d1b4d64f

Comment: @VaughnCato yeah. I guess I got fully messed-up with these pointers:) Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is here:

```
closure->method = [&a, &b, &out](){out->val = a->val + b->val;};
```

This lambda is creating a closure which references local variables.  This closure is no longer callable once the variables go out of scope.  I think you want something more like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using std::vector;
using std::function;
using std::cout;


union Value {
  bool a;
  long long val;
  int next;
};

struct Clos { //not a "closure" in its actual sense.
  vector<Value*> args;
  function<void()> method;

  ~Clos()
  {
    for (auto &arg : args) {
      delete arg;
    }
  }
};

Clos* prepare() {
  Clos* closure = new Clos();

  Value* a = new Value;
  Value* b = new Value;
  Value* out = new Value; //this exists
  closure->args.push_back(a);
  closure->args.push_back(b);
  closure->args.push_back(out);

  // Make copies of the pointers, not references.
  closure->method = [a, b, out](){out->val = a->val + b->val;};

  return closure;
}

int main(void) {
  Clos* clos = prepare();
  Value a; a.val = 7;
  Value b; b.val = 8;
  *clos->args[0] = a;
  *clos->args[1] = b;
  clos->method();
  cout << clos->args[2]->val << "\n";

  delete clos;
}
```

Comment: One question though: when args pointers get renamed (*clos->args[0] = a;) the old allocated value is garbage right? How to delete that old value, if I don't hold a reference to it?

Comment: I just now understood why this is actually not an answer to my problem: you perform a value copy for args and I want to pass them by reference :)

Comment: @artemonster: Here is another approach: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e7adc1aad4a559c